# Understanding dir() in Python

Tags: python

I was looking up the use of `dir()` in Python and I came across the following example, where `support` is just a user defined module containing the function `print_func` which prints the argument passed to it.

```
print dir(support)

Output: ['__builtins__',
        '__doc__',
        '__file__',
        '__name__',
        '__package__',
        'print_func']
```

I basically don't understand what the following statement means:

> In the call above, `__name__` is the module's filename and `__file__` is the filename from which the module was loaded.

Aren't `__name__` and `__file__` the same?

Comment: Have you looked at the two attributes; *are* they the same?

Comment: `__file__` gives you the location like `'numpy.__file__ -> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py'
`, `__name__` gives the name `numpy.__name__ -> 'numpy'
` like so they are definitely not the same

Comment: That sentence is imprecise at best, where did you find that?

Answer (score 3):

No, `__name__` and `__file__` are not the same.

`__name__` is the module name as Python sees it; it is the key by which the module is stored in `sys.modules`. For `sessions`, that'll be.... `'sessions'`.

The `__file__` attribute is the filename from which the module was loaded. It could be a `.py` file, a `.pyc` file if loaded from a bytecache, it could be a shared dynamic library file, etc.

The text you found then, is at best imprecise. Your `sessions` module could be named loaded from the file `/foo/bar/baz/sessions.py`, and then the module name `sessions` is part of the filename.

Note that `__name__` is not necessarily the name of the module as imported:

```
>>> import os.path as os_path
>>> os_path.__name__
'posixpath'
```

Two things are going on here: we imported the module under a different name; `os_path` is bound to the `os.path` module object. But `os` module does something similar: it imports a platform-specific module under a new name *too*:

```
if 'posix' in _names:
    # ....
    import posixpath as path
```

so `os.path` is really an alias for the `posixpath` module. On Windows, it'll use the `ntpath` module instead.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that `__name__` is not necessarily the name that the module is bound to in the current scope. After `import sys as foo`, `foo.__name__` is still `sys`, and after `import os`, `os.path.__name__` is whichever platform-specific module is actually loaded for use as `os.path`.

Comment: Maybe you want to mention the obvious `__name__ == '__main__'` too.